# doing xor for binaries in python

Tags: python, hash, xor

I'm in the middle of writing a simple hash function which get the input and creates a 32 bit hash file. I'm stuck in the xor part. And i'm not sure how i should write the function for xor. please help me with this. here is the code that i have done yet:

```
import BitVector
import io
import math
import struct

if __name__ == "__main__":
    message = raw_input("your message:")
    f= open('file.dat','w')
    f.write(message)
    f.close()

    f = open('file.dat')
    while 1:
       r = f.readline(1)
       hx = r.encode("hex")
       data = bin(int(hx, 16))[2:]
       key = 11111111
       x = int(data) ^ int(key)
       print hex(x)
       if not r:break
    f.close()
```

Comment: Your indentation was off. I'm not certain I got it right though; you should double-check it.

Comment: f.readline(1) will read only the single character from the file is this what you intend to do

Comment: @avasal: yes, i need to read the message bye by byte, so it get character by character as each character is one byte. am i right?

Comment: @user1222521 readline() here is not a good idea, because you should treat it a binary file, not a TEXT file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using this for xoring:

```
def xor_orig(data, key):
    return bool(data) ^ bool(key)
```

For binary xoring, where data and key are binary values and using `^` character,
you can use:

```
def xor_orig(data, key):
    return int(data,2) ^ int(key,2)


In [1]: data = '1010'
In [2]: key = '0101'    
In [3]: int(data,2) ^ int(key,2)
Out[3]: 15
In [4]: data = '10'    
In [5]: key = '01'    
In [6]: int(data,2) ^ int(key,2)
Out[6]: 3
In [7]: data = '10'    
In [8]: key = '10'    
In [9]: int(data,2) ^ int(key,2)
Out[9]: 0
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Is it all? `bool(data) ^ bool(key)` will give mostly false, as it looks like `data` is mostly non-empty list (or similar structure) and `key` is also expected to have some length.

Comment: >>> data = 0  >>> key = 1  >>> bool(data) ^ bool(key) 
[output] True

Comment: >>> `data = [0,1,2]` >>> `key = 'xyz'` >>> `bool(data) ^ bool(key)` [output] `True` (always, when `len(data) > 0` and `len(key) > 0`)

Comment: Which python version are you using coz for me 
>>> data = [0,1,2]
>>> key = 'xyz'
>>> bool(data) ^ bool(key)
[output] False
>>>

Comment: what i'm trying to do by xor function is that i need to xor the key (which here is 11111111) with the variable data (which has a value of 1s and 0s(binary)). I wanted to do it with doing (data ^ key) but it gave a value-type error.

Comment: @avasal: Of course, the result is `False`, but is `False` 100% of the described cases. Check for yourself. Hashing function which always produces zeros (or `False`s) for non-empty inputs is totally useless.

Comment: i need to xor them in binary mode. i'm confused by this. because the hash that i'm writing is the bit-by-bit exclusive-OR(xor). please guide me if you can.

Comment: @avasal: yes that was helpful. now i came up with this code that gets the input from the user change it binary then xor it with the key 8 bit by 8 bit. is this hash function correct:

Comment: where can i add my codes in this thread? i cant find the right spot to repost my code!!

Comment: @user1222521: Also add `if not hx: break` before `data = bin(int(hex, 16))[2:]` in ur updated code

Comment: @avasal: so besides what so said is the rest of this hash code right?

Answer (score 3):

The operator `^` is quite enough for you.

```
>>> 2 ^ 1
3
>>> 3 ^ 1
2
```

All you should care about is the the bit size of your key and the bit size of data to 'xor', to make sure the functionality.

By the way, xor operations should just apply to integers.

```
import struct

key = 0xFEEEFEEE
with open('file', 'rb') as f:
    integer = f.read(4) # In fact, you could read all in.
    while len(integer) >= 4:
        # if integer is not a string longer than 4, next line crash.
        s, = struct.unpack('i', integer) # The return value is a tuple with integers.
        print key ^ s
        integer = f.read(4)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i need to xor them in binary mode. i'm confused by this. because the hash that i'm writing is the bit-by-bit exclusive-OR(xor). please guide me if you can.

Comment: @user1222521: What do you mean by binary mode? Using `^` will do the same thing

Comment: then if i hex() the xor result, would it be enough as the result of this hash? i have never done any hash function before. sorry for this lack of knowledge.

Comment: im trying to send you my codes here but i cant how can i put my codes here in comment?

Comment: If you're providing more useful information, why not edit your question?

Comment: @user1222521 My code is bit-by-bit xor. That is why I care about the size (in bit). hex() would give you the right output.